# collapsible problem, i want to open only one question at time

Tags: reactjs, native

i have this collapsible, and i want to expand one question at a time
my probleme here is : whene i expand question, all questions are axpanded at the same time 
please help me solve this

i'm new in reacte native and i have tried to map and return the view but it dont work

here is the image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Dpb.png)

```
export default class AccordionHeaderContentStyleExample extends Component {


  state = {
    outerCollapse: true,
    innerCollapse: true,
  };

  render() {

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Button
              title={this.props.data.name}      
              onPress={() =>
              this.setState({ outerCollapse: !this.state.outerCollapse })}
            />
            <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.outerCollapse}>

                 {questions.map(e=>
                  <View>
                    <Button 
                       title={e.name}
                       color="#42f4eb" 
                       onPress={() => this.setState({ innerCollapse: !this.state.innerCollapse })}/>        
                     <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.innerCollapse}>
                           <Text style={styles.center}>Reponse</Text>
                      </Collapsible>
                   </View>
                     )} 

            </Collapsible>

      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

i expect to expand one question at a time.. the actual situation is whene i click, all questions are being expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your `innerCollapse` the same for every question.  I would suggest using an id for that value instead of a boolean.

```
// function outside of render
toggleQuestion = (id) =< {
    this.setState((prevState) =< {
        const isOpen = prevState.innerCollapse === id;
        return ({ innerCollapse: isOpen ? null : id });
    })
}

// Button associated with each question
onPress={() => this.toggleQuestion(question.id)}

// inner Collapsible
collapsed={this.state.innerCollapse !== question.id}
```

If the clicked question is already open, this will close it, otherwise this will set `innerCollapse` to the id of the clicked question.

Comment: thank you for your effort, but it does the same exact thing.. nothing changed
i still cant open one at a time

Comment: @SoufyaneAyanouz I updated my answer.  Give that another try :)

Comment: the same problem sir :(
i'm stuck and i have a demonstration in 1 hour with the product owner